# How to redirect in CodeIgniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to redirect to a particular page using the below code:

```
window.location.href="'<?php echo base_url() ?>'/index.php/user/view_cart/viewCart";
```

But in the url its being sent as

```
http://localhost/CI/index.php/user/view_available_books/viewAvailableBooks/'%3C?php%20echo%20base_url()%20?%3E%27/index.php/user/view_cart/viewCart
```

And i am getting output as

```
The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
```

This is my cuurent page:

```
http://localhost/CI/index.php/user/view_available_books/viewAvailableBooks/
```

This is how its redirecting:

```
http://localhost/CI/index.php/user/view_available_books/viewAvailableBooks/'%3C?php%20echo%20base_url()%20?%3E%27/index.php/user/view_cart/viewCart
```

Its taking the url of current page also while redirecting. Any Solutions?

Comment: is this code in a js file or php file??

Comment: In an external js file

Comment: then there php wont work.u need to put it in php file and also remove single quote

Comment: php don't work in js file

Comment: 1. external js can't execute php, 2. this is redirect in javascript and not CI.

Comment: I have included  in the php file and removed from that js file, still its not redirecting...same error persists

Comment: put the piece of code in php file wrapped with script tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `single quotes` from your above statement.

```
    <script>window.location.href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/user/view_cart/viewCart";</script>
```

In Condigniter, you can redirect a page using UrlHelper class.

```
    class MyController extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {

        }

        public function aFunc()
        {
            $this->load->helper('url');
            redirect('/anotherController/action/', 'refresh');
        }
```

Comment: Removing single quotes worked like a charm. It would be great if you could explain why single quotes caused this problme. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

JS file cannot process PHP. Instead you can try this changing JS to PHP file and try this:

Rename your js file from:

```
<script src="yourExternalJsFile.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script src="yourExternalJsFile.php"></script>
```

And in your php file include your script like this like this:

```
<?php header("Content-type: application/x-javascript");?>
    window.location.href="'<?php echo base_url() ?>'/index.php/user/view_cart/viewCart";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add disallowed chracters in permitted_uri_chars which exist in config file.
in cofig file

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-=';
```

but in your case you added single quote which is wrong, you have to remove single quotes.